# How to dynamically cast a variable to another type?

Tags: python, casting

Let's say in Python I have two variables of different types:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = 4
```

I want to add `B` to `A`. I can do this by putting `B` into a list, then using the `+` operator.

```
A + [B]
```

However, this only works for lists. I would like a solution that works more generally, so I can write a function called, say, `concat` that takes two things and tries to put them together. We can assume that the type of `A` will be a collection of some sort (string, list, set, etc...).

I've tried this:

```
typeA = type(A)
A + typeA(B)
```

But this results in the error `'int' is not iterable` because it's equivalent to doing `list(B)`. However, it works fine for strings and ints:

```
A = "Hello"
B = 9
typeA = type(A)
A + typeA(B)
```

I'd like to avoid a bunch of `if/else` to match every possible combination of types I'm likely to run into. Is there a "Pythonic" way of doing this?

Comment: `itertool.chains` gets you most of the way there; it takes any two iterators and returns a single iterator that yields from the first argument, then the second. That is, `list(chain(a, b)) == list(a) + list(b)`. The only issue is that it won't "promote" a non-iterable value into an iterable of one item.

Comment: 1) There is no casting Python, only conversions. 2) The title does not reflect the ask/intent which is about concat'ing things which may or may not be normally concat'able; there is no _general type conversion_ involved, rather a method/operation for an auto-coercing concat.

Comment: What's your use case for `concat`? I can't imagine one myself.

Comment: @wjandrea A special case of `concat` (the one not already handled by `chain`) would be to prepend or append a single element to an existing iterator.

Comment: @wjandrea I'm making a general-purpose `concat` that I can pass in to `reduce` to convert a collection into a different type of collection.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need some sort of conditional, but you can wrap that in a `singleton` function. This function will wrap its non-iterable argument in an iterator (specifically, a `generator`), and return its iterable argument as-is. (Beware: a `str` is iterable, so `singleton("foo")` will return `"foo"`, rather than a new iterable that yields only `"foo"`.)

```
def singleton(x):
    try:
        iter(x)
    except ValueError:
        return (y for y in (x,))
    else:
        return x
```

Then you can use `itertools.chain` to concatenate two iterables.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain([1,2,3], singleton(4)))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(chain([1,2,3], singleton((5,6))))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(chain([1,2,3], singleton("foo")))
[1, 2, 3, 'f', 'o', 'o']
```

It would be nice if `itertools` provided something like `singleton`, but the third party `more-itertools` module does provide `always_iterable`, which does the same thing (even better, it defaults to treating `str` and `bytes` as "non-iterable", with an option to iterate their contents instead.)

(Do check out [`always_iterable`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#always_iterable), even if you don't want to install the entire module. It's probably better than the hacky version of `singleton` I wrote above.)

Comment: Why do you return a generator instead of just the tuple `(x,)`? Also doesn't "singleton" mean an object that can only be instantiated once?

Comment: "Singleton" is a bit overloaded. It's a common name in Haskell for a container with exactly one element. As for the generator vs a tuple? Beats me :) I started with something like `(yield x)`, thinking I had used that or something similar to create a `generator` with only one element, and when that didn't work, I was fixated on a `generator` without considering a tuple. `always_iterable`, by the way, does return an iterator over a single tuple.